# Google Maps API v3 directions.route() request

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been converting to version 3 of the Google maps API, and keep getting an error returned when I call directionsService.route().  The map renders fine, but in Firebug I see that google throws the error "a is undefined (main.js line 16)".

Here's the relevant code:

```
self.gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id),mapOpts);

self.dirService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(self.gmap);

self.dirRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                draggable: false,
                map: self.gmap,
                markerOptions: {clickable: false}});
```

//define origin, destination, etc...

```
self.dirService.route({
'destination' : destination,
'origin' : origin,
'travelMode' : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
},function(result,status){
if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    self.dirRenderer.setDirections(result);
    self.refreshMap();
} else {
    alert(self.ERR_MapRoute);
}
});
```

On the API documentation, google says that only origin, destination, and travelMode are required in a directions request.  Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error using overlays which are not present on Map. Or something got wrong with the initialization.
Check your initializations, you may have missed something.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I got it figured out.  What worked was, instead of calling the custom self.refreshMap() in the callback for DirectionsService.route(), I added a listener to the directionRenderer's direction changed event:

Comment: the listener I added was:
    google.maps.event.addListener(self.dirRenderer,'directions_changed',function(){  google.maps.event.trigger(this.getMap(),'resize');});

then I removed the self.refreshMap() from the route() callback